# MySQL Alternative to Trigger on Select

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

For a project I am currently working on, I am required to use triggers to restrict users' access to a database. However, since there are no triggers on SELECT statements, I need to find some alternative method for adding restrictions before a SELECT statement is executed. Are there any alternatives to "Triggers on SELECT"? if so, what are they?

Note: This is an assignment, thus I cannot add the restrictions at application level since the point of the assignment is to add restrictions at the DB Level.

I have also read all other posts that I can find on this, please don't close this post pointing me to some other related posts unless they have several alternatives I can choose from. I'm not saying these posts are of no use or the solutions are not proper, However, I would like to explore all of the possible solutions.

Comment: Perhaps you could indicate which other posts you have found, or what they recommend, and why any suggestions contained therein are of no use to you?  If table-level permissions are of no use, then my only thought is to deny users access to directly select from the relevant tables - instead forcing them to use sprocs in which you verify authorisation; however, this merely moves what is essentially business logic from application code into the database - and it may be undesirable to you for any number of reasons.

Comment: There are a few posts that comes up as related on your right here on SO. I'm not saying these posts are of no use, I'm just saying I would like to explore all of the possible solutions.

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to change the table to a view, such that querying the view invokes a stored function, and the stored function logs access to the table.

Here's a blog by the great Roland Bouman, describing the process in detail:
http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2005/08/mysql-create-dirty-little-tricker-for.html